# Trying to create a dropdown selection menu with React's <select> and map users from an array as an option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple app to add users to a database (MongoDb) and display the list of users in a drop down menu.

In the form I am getting two errors, one with the  closing tag ( i.e. ) and with mapping the list of users from an array.

Below is my form, after the render() method.

I have tried changing to , which gets rid of one of the errors, but after reading the React docs i dont see why  shouldn't work.

The second error is with the map function (this.state.users.map((user) => {)

```
 render() { 
        return ( 
        <div>
            <h3>Create new exercise log</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}> 
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Username: </label>
                    <select ref="userInput"
                        required
                        className="form-control"
                        value={this.state.username}
                        onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                        {
                            this.state.users.map((user) => {
                                return <option
                                    key={user}
                                    value={user}>{user}
                                    </option>;
                            })
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

For the moment, the users array is a hard coded array as I haven't added to DB yet:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ //set the state of the users array
            users: ['test user'], 
            username: 'test user'
        })
    }
```

This is the error in the browser:

```
  Line 75:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

  73 |                         onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
  74 |                         {
> 75 |                             this.state.users.map((user) => {
     |                             ^
  76 |                                 return <option
  77 |                                     key={user}
  78 |                                     value={user}>{user}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the `select` opening tag with `>` :

```
<select ref="userInput"
  required
  className="form-control"
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={this.onChangeUsername} > //<== Here
      {
          this.state.users.map((user) => {
              return <option
                  key={user}
                  value={user}>{user}
                  </option>;
          })
      }
</select>
```

Comment: The closing tag is in ``` value={user}>{user}```

Comment: It closes the `option`, not the `select`, try it

Comment: I've just added the browser error which says it can't parse "this", but I don't understand why.

Comment: Try a different editor/install extensions specific to React/JSX to pick up on these easier.